# Should I pin down package requirements if I am using pipenv or poetry?

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, pipenv, python-poetry

I am used to using pip for my package dependencies. I am playing around with pipenv and poetry. It seems like both of these tools are a lot better.

One question I have though whether I should lock my package versions when I am installing them. For example, right now my Pipfile shows that I have a package `django = "*"`. On the other hand, my Pipfile.lock shows that I have the following:

```
"django": {
    "hashes": [
        "sha256:xxxxxxxxxx",
        "sha256:xxxxxxxxx"
    ],
    "index": "pypi",
    "version": "==4.2.2"
},
```

Is the versioning from Pipfile.lock good enough to make sure that I will not accidentally get Django 5.0 when it releases? Or should I lock that dependency by using following:

```
pipenv install django==4.2.2
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: From my point of view, in something like `Pipfile` or `pyproject.toml` the only thing you should do is exclude the versions that you know are incompatible. You have the *lock file* for the "*known good set*".